# MySQL UPDATE Time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a program and I have created a leaderboards online, it is going to show 'Total Time Ran' to update it I am using INSERT and

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Time=Time+'$time',
```

The problem with this is that it will insert fine and then show the first time but then when it comes to updating it using ON DUPLICATE it resets to 00:00:00, I have the program sending it in the hh:mm:ss format and in the databse, the field 'Time' uses the type 'time'.

What can I change to make it so it works and doesn't reset to 00:00:00 each time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert $time to seconds and use

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Time=Time+INTERVAL $time SECOND
```

Comment: The first update works fine, but then the second one I get the error: Column 'Time' cannot be null

Answer (score 1):

You can't add dates together like that. Try

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Time=TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, xxx, Time)
```

where  xxx is the number of seconds spent running. This'll properly update the time field.